# jQuery fadein when loaded with timer

Tags: jquery, load, fadein, fadeout

I want to build a script that loads a external file into a DIV when the page is loaded, and then fades the content in as soon as the content has been loaded completely. Then I want to display the first div for 60 seconds, and then fadeout the first div and fadein the second div as soon as it has loaded completely.

Now I have to different processes in my script so now it reloads the content of the div while it's visible... I want to reload the div before it fades in, and then display for 60 seconds, and do the same process with the next div.

Can anyone help me out? I|ve been trying a lot of things here, but can't get that to work as I want it to.

This is the code I have so far;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Title
</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var divs = $('.fade');

function fade() {
    var current = $('.current');
    var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);

    next.stop().fadeIn(3000, function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });

    current.stop().fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(fade, 60000);
    });
}

fade();
});//]]>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    cache: false,
    async:false
});
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#div1').load('content1.php');
    $('#div2').load('content2.php');
    $('#div3').load('content3.php');
    $('#div4').load('content4.php');
    $('#div5').load('content5.php');

});
function div1()
{
 $('#div1').load('content1.php');
}
setInterval('div1()', 50000);

function div2()
{
 $('#div2').load('content2.php');
}
setInterval('div2()', 50000);

function div3()
{
 $('#div3').load('content3.php');
}
setInterval('div3()', 50000);

function div4()
{
 $('#div4').load('content4.php');
}
setInterval('div4()', 50000);
</script>

<style>
body {margin:0;}
.fade {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
.current {z-index:999;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1" class="fade current"></div>
    <div id="div2" class="fade"></div>
    <div id="div3" class="fade"></div>
    <div id="div4" class="fade"></div>
    <div id="div5" class="fade"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please set up a fiddle

Comment: Done :) Here is the fiddle @TheMohanAhuja ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/fwqC4/

Comment: Anyways your fiddle won't work here I guess :)

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja You can have a look here; http://www.zorensen.no/ajax

It doesn't work. As I said, I want to display DIV1, DIV2 etc. up until nr. 5 and then loop the whole thing to start over from number 1 again. This script I have so far just displays DIV1 and nothing more happens.

Just to be really clear;
1) I want to fadein the div AFTER it's completely loaded
2) Fadein/out DIV1-5
3) Then loop it so it starts over again

Comment: have you tried jfreind00 suggestion, I checked his code is working for what you want? if there is something missing then I would help you with it.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried everything he told me. It's not working. The script is just diplaying one or two divs before it stops completely... Something is wrong with jfriend00s code underneath, but I can't figure out what it is.... Want to help out @TheMohanAhuja?

Answer (score -1):

Here's one concept for doing this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    async:true          // you really want to allow async ajax
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    var divs = $();

    function markLoaded() {
        var self = $(this);
        self.data("loaded", true);

        function next(item) {
            // if we're the current item and we are loaded
            // then show us.  If we're not yet loaded, then do
            // nothing here and we will get shown when
            // markLoaded is called
            if (item.hasClass("current") && item.data("loaded")) {
                item.fadeIn(3000, function() {
                    // move current to the next one
                    item.removeClass("current");
                    var index = (divs.index(item) + 1) % divs.length;
                    var nextItem = divs.eq(index);
                    // display for 60 seconds before fading out
                    item.delay(60 * 1000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
                        nextItem.addClass("current");
                        // Now that this is hidden and we're temporarily done with, 
                        // reload the content for this div for the next time it is displayed.
                        // This will essentially preload the content so it should be ready
                        // when it's time to display this div.
                        item.data("loaded", false);
                        item.load(item.data("url"), markLoaded);
                        // now get the next item going
                        next(nextItem);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        next(self);
    }

    // hide all the divs and start the content loading into them
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var item = $("#div" + i);
        var content = 'content' + i + '.php';
        item.data("url", content);
        divs = divs.add(item);
        item.hide().load(content, markLoaded);
    }
});
```

Simulation working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/seLet/

Here's the general logic:

1. Always use async for Ajax calls - non-async locks up the browser which is really bad for the user experience.
2. The divs are all loaded in a loop (rather than duplicating code).
3. When any div has finished loading, it is displayed if it has the `class="current"` (only one will have that)
4. This will obviously show div1 first since it is the only one with the `class="current"`
5. After div1 fades in, it removes the "current" class from itself
6. It then calculates which div is next, fades out the one that is displaying, adds the `"current"` class to the new one and calls `next(nextItem)`.
7. As soon as a div finishes fading out, we reset it's state and tell it to load new content again so it will have fresh content the next time it displays (preloads content)
8. If that div has finished loading, it starts to fade in
9. If it hasn't yet finished loading, then the code does nothing and it will get displayed when it finishes loading and markLoaded is called on it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this! :) What do I do if the DIV or the files loaded into the DIV is named something else than "Div1", "Div2" etc. and "content1.php", "content2.php" etc.?

Lets say the first div is name "myfirstdiv" and the second one is name "andthisismyseconddiv"? :)

Comment: @zorensen - you can put the various names into an array and pull out the first name from `names[0]` and the second one from `names[1]` and so on.  The principle of [DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is that you should not have multiple copies of the same code anywhere.  Put common code into functions and call those functions or organize repetitive code into loops.  When you need to carry out the same operation on a number of different items, put those items into an array and iterate over the array.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I tried your code, and it just displays the first DIV. It never fades into the next div here...

Comment: @zorensen - Do u have a test page I can see to debug?

Comment: I've been trying very hard here, @jfriend00. Can't really get it to work. Also, I want to loop this scripts, so when it has displayed DIV5 it should start over again.

Comment: @zorensen - I fixed one script error in my answer (been away from computer all day until now).  I don't have any ability to run the fixed code so you'll have to try that and report whether that works or gets you to a next issue. The code is already designed to loop and repeat.  If this fix doesn't work, please look in the debug console for any script errors and use that to help troubleshoot and we'll find/fix the next issue.

Comment: @zorensen - here's a simulation (uses `setTimeout()` instead of `.load()` and uses shorter animation timings) that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/seLet/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55410/discussion-between-zorensen-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @zorensen - I've modified the code in my answer to now continuously reload new content before displaying each time.

Comment: I've tried your code now, and sometimes it stops after two fades. Sometimes it runs through all the divs, but doesn't start over again. Doesn't seem like the loop is working. I've sent you the URL and my console in chat so you can have a look at it @jfriend00